# How to exclude default API route version from non-default version document

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, aspnet-api-versioning

I have an ASP.NET Core (3.1) API that use the [aspnet-api-versioning](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning) (4.1.1) library for versioning. The project is setup to read the version from the URL and use a default version (1) if no version is specified. The example controller supports two API versions (1 and 2) and has two identical methods, one for each version. Since a default version is supported there are two Route attributes on the controller, one without the version and one with.

When generating the OpenAPI documentation for the API, using the [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) (5.6.3) library, both the document for API version 1 and 2 will include the non-versioned route; "/Customer/{externalCustomerId}". The problem to solve is, how to configure the Swagger generation to only include the non-versioned routes in the documentation for the default version? Given the code below, the documentation for version 1 should be:

- /Customer/{externalCustomerId}
- /v1/Customer/[externalCustomerId}

and the documentation for version 2 should be:

- /v2/Customer/{externalCustomerId}

Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    ... // Removed for brevity. Method below called from ConfigureServices(...).
    private static void ConfigureApiVersioning(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(setup =>
        {
            setup.GroupNameFormat = "'v'V";
            setup.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
        });

        services.AddApiVersioning(setup =>
        {
            setup.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            setup.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(majorVersion: 1, minorVersion: 0);
            setup.ReportApiVersions = true;
            setup.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
        });
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Route("Customer")]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/Customer")]
[ApiVersion("1", Deprecated = true)]
[ApiVersion("2")]
[ApiController]
public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{externalCustomerId}")]
    [MapToApiVersion("1")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Customer Api v1 responded with 200 ok";
    }

    [HttpGet("{externalCustomerId}")]
    [MapToApiVersion("2")]
    public string GetV2()
    {
        return "Customer Api v2 responded with 200 ok";
    }
}
```

Can (should) it be solved using `SwaggerGenOptions.DocInclusionPredicate()` somehow? I gave it a go, but could not figure out a way to get the default API version from the `ApiVersion` of the predicate.

One option may be to inherit from the `DefaultApiVersionDescriptionProvider` (or implement `IApiVersionDescriptionProvider`) to get access to the Options property, which would allow us to get the default API version and use a predicate with a closure in Startup for `SwaggerGenOptions.DocInclusionPredicate()`, but is that a good approach to take? What other options exist?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities:

- Use `DocInclusionPredicate`
- Use a custom **IOperationFilter**
- Use a custom **IApiDescriptionProvider**

The first one is probably the simplest. Since all properly versioned routes have the route parameter in it, you'd just exclude any that contain it. Something like:

```cs
c.DocInclusionPredicate((d, api) => !api.RelativePath.Contains("v{version:apiVersion}"))
```

You'll need to remove/disable `options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl`; you're not using it anyway.

> You should think carefully about what your API documentation is conveying; it's misleading. The OpenAPI/Swagger document will show the correct routes for `2.0`; however, when a client requests it, they will get `1.0`. This happens because you've allowed no version to be specified and you assume `1.0`. You *could* use an alternate **IApiVersionSelector** such as **CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector**, but that would merely invert the problem. The purpose of versioning is so that a client can explicitly ask for the version they want.